# Unable to create an XML File using Eclipse Juno

Tags: xml, eclipse

I am currently using Eclipse JUNO . I am unable to find the way to create an XML file using Eclipse JUNO.

I have navigated to File->New->Other >..   But unable to find the XML wizard under it.

Do I need to install a separate plugin for creating XML files ?

Answer (score 0):

Use `File -> New File` or `File -> File` and give the entire file name (specify the .xml file extension).